# Combining queries from a single table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 queries. The first query get the product title, the second query get the product image and create grid layout. Both query doing lookup on 1 table.

```
$sql = "SELECT post_title FROM `wordpress`.`wp_posts` ".
          "WHERE post_type ='wpsc-product' ".
          "AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`ID`"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $title = $row['post_title']; 
}

$sql2 = "SELECT guid FROM `wordpress`.`wp_posts` ".
        "WHERE post_mime_type ='image/png' ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`ID`"; 
echo "<table border=\"10\" style=\"margin-top:10px;\">"; 
echo "<tr>"; 
$i=1; 
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error()); 


while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) ){ 

    $image = $row2['guid']; 
    echo "<td><a href=".$image.">".
         "<IMG style=\"width:100px;height:100px;".
                      "vertical-align:top; padding-right: 10px; " . 
                       ( ($i %2 == "0") ? "padding-left: 30px;" : "") . 
        "  \" SRC=\"$image\" ALT=\"align box\" ALIGN=LEFT></a>"; 

    echo "<a style=\"text-decoration:underline;\" ".
             "onmouseover=\"this.style.textDecoration = 'none'\" ".
             "onmouseout=\"this.style.textDecoration = 'underline'\"".
             "href=".$lol.">$title</a><br>"; 
    echo "<p style=\"color:#990000; padding-top:5px; font-weight:bold;\">".
           " $19.90</p> <a style=\"font-weight:lighter;\" href=".$lol.">".
           "More info<img style=\"padding-left:3px;\" ".
            "src=\"http://localhost/famfamfam.png\"></a></td>"; 
    if ($i++ % 2 == 0) { 
       echo "</tr><tr><td style=\"padding-right:20px;\" colspan=\"1\">".
            "<hr style=\"width:250px;\" /></td> ".
            "<td style=\"padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 30px;\" ".
            "colspan=\"1\"><hr style=\"width:250px;\" /></td></tr>"; 
    } 
} 
echo "</tr></table>";
```

I want to use the result from first query($title) and use it in the second while loop query ($title).

How do I do that. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

@Muhammad Yasir and @cwallenpoole both of you answer did not work but I prefer @cwallenpoole idea because you use a single query. 
Here is the image output of both of your guys answer. It's the same: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysqWf.png

I actually manage to filter the result with php but I was hoping I could refine the query result with sql instead.

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `wordpress`.`wp_posts`";  
echo "<table border=\"10\" style=\"margin-top:10px;\">";  
echo "<tr>";  
$i=1;  
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());  


while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) ){  

if ($row2['post_status'] == 'publish' && $row2['post_type'] == 'wpsc-product'){ 
       $title = $row2['post_title']; 
} 

//echo  $row2['guid']; 

if ($row2['post_mime_type'] == 'image/png' ) 
{ 
$image = $row2['guid']; 



            echo "<td><a href=".$image."><IMG style=\"width:100px;height:100px;vertical-align:top; padding-right: 10px; " . ( ($i %2 == "0") ? "padding-left: 30px;" : "") . "  \" SRC=\"$image  \" ALT=\"align box\" ALIGN=LEFT></a>";  

    echo "<a style=\"text-decoration:underline;\" onmouseover=\"this.style.textDecoration = 'none'\" onmouseout=\"this.style.textDecoration = 'underline'\" href=".$lol."> $title  </a><br>";  
    echo "<p style=\"color:#990000; padding-top:5px; font-weight:bold;\"> $19.90</p> <a style=\"font-weight:lighter;\" href=".$lol.">More info<img style=\"padding-left:3px;\" src=\"http://localhost/famfamfam.png\"></a>  
</td>";  
    if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {  
       echo "</tr><tr><td style=\"padding-right:20px;\" colspan=\"1\"><hr style=\"width:250px;\" /></td> <td style=\"padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 30px;\" colspan=\"1\"><hr style=\"width:250px;\" /></td></tr>";  
    }  
} 




}  
echo "</tr></table>";
```

and the output I wanted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqLRp.png

Here is the sql file. I hope someone could help me to optimize my code.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.2.4
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Aug 16, 2011 at 06:07 AM
-- Server version: 5.1.41
-- PHP Version: 5.3.1

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `wordpress`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_posts`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` text NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_posts`
--

INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2011-08-16 01:32:00', '2011-08-16 01:32:00', 'Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!', 'Hello world!', '', 'publish', 'open', 'open', '', 'hello-world', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:32:00', '2011-08-16 01:32:00', '', 0, 'http://localhost/?p=1', 0, 'post', '', 1),
(2, 1, '2011-08-16 01:32:00', '2011-08-16 01:32:00', 'This is an example page. It''s different from a blog post because it will stay in one place and will show up in your site navigation (in most themes). Most people start with an About page that introduces them to potential site visitors. It might say something like this:\n\n<blockquote>Hi there! I''m a bike messenger by day, aspiring actor by night, and this is my blog. I live in Los Angeles, have a great dog named Jack, and I like pi&#241;a coladas. (And gettin'' caught in the rain.)</blockquote>\n\n...or something like this:\n\n<blockquote>The XYZ Doohickey Company was founded in 1971, and has been providing quality doohickies to the public ever since. Located in Gotham City, XYZ employs over 2,000 people and does all kinds of awesome things for the Gotham community.</blockquote>\n\nAs a new WordPress user, you should go to <a href="http://localhost/wp-admin/">your dashboard</a> to delete this page and create new pages for your content. Have fun!', 'Sample Page', '', 'publish', 'open', 'open', '', 'sample-page', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:32:00', '2011-08-16 01:32:00', '', 0, 'http://localhost/?page_id=2', 0, 'page', '', 0),
(3, 1, '2011-08-16 01:37:18', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', 'Auto Draft', '', 'auto-draft', 'open', 'open', '', '', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:37:18', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', 0, 'http://localhost/?p=3', 0, 'post', '', 0),
(4, 1, '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '[productspage]', 'Products Page', '', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'products-page', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '', 0, 'http://localhost/?page_id=4', 0, 'page', '', 0),
(5, 1, '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '[shoppingcart]', 'Checkout', '', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'checkout', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '', 4, 'http://localhost/?page_id=5', 0, 'page', '', 0),
(6, 1, '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '[transactionresults]', 'Transaction Results', '', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'transaction-results', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '', 4, 'http://localhost/?page_id=6', 0, 'page', '', 0),
(7, 1, '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '[userlog]', 'Your Account', '', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'your-account', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '2011-08-16 01:38:28', '', 4, 'http://localhost/?page_id=7', 0, 'page', '', 0),
(8, 1, '2011-08-16 01:42:13', '2011-08-16 01:42:13', 'this\r\n\r\nis\r\n\r\na\r\n\r\ntst', 'Kaspersky Internet Security', '', 'publish', 'open', 'closed', '', 'kaspersky-internet-security', '', '', '2011-08-16 02:29:33', '2011-08-16 02:29:33', '', 0, 'http://localhost/?post_type=wpsc-product&#038;p=8', 0, 'wpsc-product', '', 0),
(9, 1, '2011-08-16 01:41:49', '2011-08-16 01:41:49', '', '5580', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', '5580', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:41:49', '2011-08-16 01:41:49', '', 8, 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/55803.png', 0, 'attachment', 'image/png', 0),
(10, 1, '2011-08-16 01:45:38', '2011-08-16 01:45:38', 'this\r\n\r\nis\r\n\r\na\r\n\r\ntest', 'Logitech M508', '', 'publish', 'open', 'closed', '', 'logitech-m508', '', '', '2011-08-16 02:35:18', '2011-08-16 02:35:18', '', 0, 'http://localhost/?post_type=wpsc-product&#038;p=10', 0, 'wpsc-product', '', 0),
(11, 1, '2011-08-16 01:45:18', '2011-08-16 01:45:18', '', 'wormmm', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', 'wormmm', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:45:18', '2011-08-16 01:45:18', '', 10, 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/wormmm2.png', 0, 'attachment', 'image/png', 0),
(12, 1, '2011-08-16 01:48:16', '2011-08-16 01:48:16', 'this\r\n\r\nis\r\n\r\na\r\n\r\ntest', 'StG 44', '', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'stg-44', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:48:16', '2011-08-16 01:48:16', '', 0, 'http://localhost/?post_type=wpsc-product&#038;p=12', 0, 'wpsc-product', '', 0),
(13, 1, '2011-08-16 01:48:00', '2011-08-16 01:48:00', '', 'port', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', 'port', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:48:00', '2011-08-16 01:48:00', '', 12, 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/port.png', 0, 'attachment', 'image/png', 0),
(14, 1, '2011-08-16 01:49:41', '2011-08-16 01:49:41', 'this\r\n\r\nis\r\n\r\na\r\n\r\ntst', 'Bullet train', '', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'bullet-train', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:49:41', '2011-08-16 01:49:41', '', 0, 'http://localhost/?post_type=wpsc-product&#038;p=14', 0, 'wpsc-product', '', 0),
(15, 1, '2011-08-16 01:49:24', '2011-08-16 01:49:24', '', 'KIS', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', 'kis', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:49:24', '2011-08-16 01:49:24', '', 14, 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/KIS.png', 0, 'attachment', 'image/png', 0),
(16, 1, '2011-08-16 01:50:39', '2011-08-16 01:50:39', 'this \r\n\r\nis\r\n\r\na\r\n\r\ntest', 'Stack Over Flow', '', 'publish', 'open', 'closed', '', 'stack-over-flow', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:50:39', '2011-08-16 01:50:39', '', 0, 'http://localhost/?post_type=wpsc-product&#038;p=16', 0, 'wpsc-product', '', 0),
(18, 1, '2011-08-16 01:57:26', '2011-08-16 01:57:26', '', 'cat', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', 'cat', '', '', '2011-08-16 01:57:26', '2011-08-16 01:57:26', '', 16, 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/cat.png', 0, 'attachment', 'image/png', 0),
(19, 1, '2011-08-16 02:26:40', '2011-08-16 02:26:40', '[productspage]', '', '', 'publish', 'open', 'open', '', '19', '', '', '2011-08-16 02:27:36', '2011-08-16 02:27:36', '', 0, 'http://localhost/?p=19', 2, 'nav_menu_item', '', 0),
(20, 1, '2011-08-16 02:26:40', '2011-08-16 02:26:40', '[userlog]', '', '', 'publish', 'open', 'open', '', '20', '', '', '2011-08-16 02:27:36', '2011-08-16 02:27:36', '', 4, 'http://localhost/?p=20', 3, 'nav_menu_item', '', 0),
(21, 1, '2011-08-16 02:26:40', '2011-08-16 02:26:40', '[transactionresults]', '', '', 'publish', 'open', 'open', '', '21', '', '', '2011-08-16 02:27:36', '2011-08-16 02:27:36', '', 4, 'http://localhost/?p=21', 5, 'nav_menu_item', '', 0),
(22, 1, '2011-08-16 02:26:40', '2011-08-16 02:26:40', '[shoppingcart]', '', '', 'publish', 'open', 'open', '', '22', '', '', '2011-08-16 02:27:36', '2011-08-16 02:27:36', '', 4, 'http://localhost/?p=22', 4, 'nav_menu_item', '', 0),
(23, 1, '2011-08-16 02:26:40', '2011-08-16 02:26:40', 'This is an example page. It’s different from a blog post because it will stay in one place and will show up in your site navigation (in most themes). Most people start with an About page that introduces them to potential site visitors. It might say something like this:\r\n\r\nHi there! I’m a bike messenger by day, aspiring actor by night, and this is my blog. I live in Los Angeles, have a great dog named Jack, and I like piña coladas. (And gettin’ caught in the rain.)\r\n\r\n…or something like this:\r\n\r\nThe XYZ Doohickey Company was founded in 1971, and has been providing quality doohickies to the public ever since. Located in Gotham City, XYZ employs over 2,000 people and does all kinds of awesome things for the Gotham community.\r\n\r\nAs a new WordPress user, you should go to your dashboard to delete this page and create new pages for your content. Have fun!', '', '', 'publish', 'open', 'open', '', '23', '', '', '2011-08-16 02:27:35', '2011-08-16 02:27:35', '', 0, 'http://localhost/?p=23', 1, 'nav_menu_item', '', 0),
(24, 1, '2011-08-16 02:28:11', '2011-08-16 02:28:11', 'null', 'Stack Over Flow (1 PC (1 Year))', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', 'stack-over-flow-1-pc-1-year', '', '', '2011-08-16 02:28:11', '2011-08-16 02:28:11', '', 16, 'http://localhost/?wpsc-product=stack-over-flow-1-pc-1-year', 0, 'wpsc-product', '', 0),
(25, 1, '2011-08-16 02:28:11', '2011-08-16 02:28:11', 'null', 'Stack Over Flow (3 PC (1 Year))', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', 'stack-over-flow-3-pc-1-year', '', '', '2011-08-16 02:28:11', '2011-08-16 02:28:11', '', 16, 'http://localhost/?wpsc-product=stack-over-flow-3-pc-1-year', 0, 'wpsc-product', '', 0),
(26, 1, '2011-08-16 02:28:55', '2011-08-16 02:28:55', 'null', 'Kaspersky Internet Security (1 PC (1 Year))', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', 'kaspersky-internet-security-1-pc-1-year', '', '', '2011-08-16 02:28:55', '2011-08-16 02:28:55', '', 8, 'http://localhost/?wpsc-product=kaspersky-internet-security-1-pc-1-year', 0, 'wpsc-product', '', 0),
(27, 1, '2011-08-16 02:28:55', '2011-08-16 02:28:55', 'null', 'Kaspersky Internet Security (3 PC (1 Year))', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', 'kaspersky-internet-security-3-pc-1-year', '', '', '2011-08-16 02:28:55', '2011-08-16 02:28:55', '', 8, 'http://localhost/?wpsc-product=kaspersky-internet-security-3-pc-1-year', 0, 'wpsc-product', '', 0);
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable like `$j`:

```
$j = 0;    
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) ){ 
    $t = $title[$j]; // this will be your title
    $image = $row2['guid']; 
    echo "<td><a href=".$image."><IMG style=\"width:100px;height:100px;vertical-align:top; padding-right: 10px; " . ( ($i %2 == "0") ? "padding-left: 30px;" : "") . "  \" SRC=\"$image\" ALT=\"align box\" ALIGN=LEFT></a>"; 

    echo "<a style=\"text-decoration:underline;\" onmouseover=\"this.style.textDecoration = 'none'\" onmouseout=\"this.style.textDecoration = 'underline'\" href=".$lol.">$title</a><br>"; 
    echo "<p style=\"color:#990000; padding-top:5px; font-weight:bold;\"> $19.90</p> <a style=\"font-weight:lighter;\" href=".$lol.">More info<img style=\"padding-left:3px;\" src=\"http://localhost/famfamfam.png\"></a> 
</td>"; 
    if ($i++ % 2 == 0) { 
       echo "</tr><tr><td style=\"padding-right:20px;\" colspan=\"1\"><hr style=\"width:250px;\" /></td> <td style=\"padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 30px;\" colspan=\"1\"><hr style=\"width:250px;\" /></td></tr>"; 
    }
    $j++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the first query. I think you can get away with:

```
// use instead of your second query... notice the addition of post_title.
$sql2 = "SELECT guid, post_title FROM `wordpress`.`wp_posts` ".
    "WHERE post_mime_type ='image/png' ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`ID`"; 

// later! (you've done stuff in the meanwhile!)
// note: assoc is used because it is technically more appropriate
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2) ){ 

    $image = $row2['guid']; 
    // this will always be the title which goes with the guid!
    $title = $row2['post_title'];
```

Comment: @Muhammad Yasir Unfortunately it does not work. I update my detail above. Thanks for trying though :)